# Jenkins Google Login Plugin Redirect URIs error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured the Jenkins and needed to enable Google Login Plugin. As per plugin documentation I'm trying to create a Google Client-id. In the documentation it says enter "**Redirect URIs**" as follows. But when I enter this in the App console to generate the client id Google says it "Invalid URL"

```
http://XX.XX.228.XX:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin
```

When I directly loaded this page in the browser this error is shown up with 500 status code
[image]

Note: My url is a public url

Answer (score 0):

The authorized redirect URLs (second input in form) should be, url of your `Jenkins + '/securityRealm/finishLogin'`

Did you put this ? Do you have more details?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not allow public IP addresses in the Authorized Redirect URIs. This might be one of the reasons that cause this exception.